# ASP.NET 5 DNX issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dnx

I have the following error when I try to start my ASP.NET 5 web application

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How I can fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hn90g.png)

Comment: What version of .net are you running? There have been changes to the DNX host fairly recently.

Comment: In my project I use beta6 of DNX SDK, I know that they've changed a lot. But I can't get it worked..

Comment: @Arsen, move to at least 8 or RC1.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/51) you need to update your beta6 runtime to newer one.
Update your runtime via `dnvm upgrade` and project.json:

update all `...-beta6` packages to `...-rc1-final`

Comment: How can I do this? Where I can write dnvm upgrade?

Comment: Yes! I've updated just now from comand prompt. But shall I need to do something else? I have the same issue when I run my website

Comment: I've just closed/opened VS and get many errors. It says I need to execute "dnu restore". I do that, but it fails - http://screencast.com/t/afqx7A4tYg. Do you know why?

Comment: @АрсенМовсесьян Which version of VS are you using? Go to https://get.asp.net/ there are instructions how to update aspnet 5

Comment: I'm using VisualStudio 2015

Comment: @АрсенМовсесьян download https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=627627 install file from this link and update visual studio

Comment: https://get.asp.net/ will also give you the new installers. You also have to update all your nuget refrences to match the current version you are building against. And you will have to edit any breaking changes they did since beta6 if that was what you upgraded from.